# Issue in Multi list with search for Italy version

Tags: sitecore

I have issue in Multi list with Search in Sitecore. I'm using Sitecore 8.1 along with Solr 6.5. I'm using the below query to load the items in the multi list. Items are loading perfectly on English version. But when I switched to Italian version for same item, no items are loading.

**Query:**

```
StartSearchLocation=query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename->'Site Folder']//*[@@templatename->'Products Folder']
```

When I googled for this issue many recommend that to use the latest version filter in the query. So I did like this.

```
StartSearchLocation=query:./ancestor::*[@@templatename->'Site Folder']//*[@@templatename->'Products Folder']&Filter=+_latestversion:true
```

But this also doesn't help me. When further digging on this issue I got some hint which says,

This will happen when an item has more than one version. Not in the means of language but multiple versions in same language.

So I tried removing multiple versions in same language. Also no luck. Same query working for other languages. But issue is in Italian language only.

Can someone please help on this issue to get solved? Yes I know Multi list with search has bugs, but more than that my requirement was to use multi list with search. Please do let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: >"Same query working for other languages"< : can you check if Site Folder and Product Folder for Italian version exists and not stuck in workflow ?

Comment: Yes Naveen Ahmad. Both the Products and Site folder is  present in Italian version. All the products are displaying once I unselect the selected items in multi list.